# How do I store "multiple pieces of information" of an item in Java

Tags: java

I need a Data Structure that will allow me to store at least 2 pieces of data per item. I want the items to be store in the order they were inserted in.

Example:

```
Insert (xyz, string) ... insert (789, number)
System.out.println( dataStruct );
```

will print out `(xyz, string)` then `(789,number)`

If possible, please show some sample codes. Thank you!

Comment: May I at least know why am I getting down votes?

Comment: Please mention clearly that whether you are looking for key-value pairs, as we have in `HashTable`, every key will be having one value. Please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: Your question is not very easy to understand, the initial formatting was awful, and a simple google query might have given you an answer too. You should probably read [ask] and [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), if you want to improve your questions.

Comment: @Ars - Thanks. I am really just asking for suggestions.. since I just started learning Java. And I already gave all the information I know..

Comment: @nfechner - Thanks. I actually tried Google first then I thought the best idea was to just ask people base on their experience. Oh well. Thanks for formatting it btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Store {
String str1;
String str2;

public Store(String string1, String string2) {
    str1 = string1;
    str2 = string2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Store[] s = new Store[10]; // size
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = new Store("A", "B");
        System.out.println(s[i].str1);
        System.out.println(s[i].str2);

    }

}
}
```

I think this is what you are searching for . This is  C like structure. Try this.
This will help you to insert more than 2 piece of data per item  by just doing little changes. And order will be maintained too.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while but I finally see the connection of this code between C and Java! Thanks! And I used an ArrayList<Class> to simply it a little :P

Answer (score 1):

The below code can be your data structure :

```
 List<Item> list;

    class Item {
     public String desc;
     public Integer val;
     void insert(String desc,Integer val){
     this.desc = desc;
     this.val = val; 
     }   
     void insert(Integer val,String desc){
     insert(desc,val);
     }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of using something like a C struct so this Java code looks a bit strange to me.. So you are creating a List of a <Item> class?

Comment: yes, list of <Items> and irrespective of string,int or int,string it populates the Item.

Comment: Thank you! I will research on this List data structure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) or a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Example:

```
Hashtable<Integer,String> hTable=new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
//adding or set items in Hashtable by put method key and value pair
hTable.put(new Integer(2), "Two");
hTable.put(new Integer(1), "One");
hTable.put(new Integer(4), "Four");
hTable.put(new Integer(3), "Three");
hTable.put(new Integer(5), "Five");
```

Take a look at some [Java structures](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_data_structures.htm).

EDIT

In order to keep the insertion order one can use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) or [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Dictionary is marked as obsolete. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html)

Comment: Thank you, changed it to Hashtable.

Comment: `Hashtable` is synchronized. You should usually have a good reason to use it. Otherwise a simple `HashMap` will be faster.

Comment: @MeNoMore - Thank you! but I really just need a First in First out ordering data structure.. I guess I could add a third piece of data like a counter to help sort it? Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Dino55 In that case, take a look at java.util.LinkedList. In general, you should study the java.util collections. They are basic utility classes that get used in most non-trivial Java applications.

Comment: A LinkedHashMap keeps the insertion order

Comment: @lbalazscs right, the LinkedHashSet does this too. i write this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will somehow fill the requirement,you can also use parameters of the type in the constructors of HashMap.

```
HashMap map= new HashMap();
List<HashMap> virtualDs= new ArrayList<HashMap>();
```